# Does core data have FIFO?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fifo

I would like to ask is there any FIFO examples for swift coredata?

For example, I only allow user to stores 50 history. So when a user store another history, no. 51 will be entered, and no. 1 in core data will be deleted automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think *FIFO* means what you think it means

Comment: you have to manually do like you want. Basically coredata is creating sqlite file So, It has same behaviour like sqlite database.

Comment: @JitendraModi Thanks for the advice! I will try it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do this yourself. Managed objects aren't created or deleted automatically in most cases, so if you want to limit the number of instances of an entity, you need to write code to do that.

You'll probably need to add an attribute to your entity to keep track of the order, so that your code would know which was the first, second, etc, and work out which instance(s) to delete. That could be an integer index, or a creation date, or maybe something else.

Comment: Thanks for the useful advices, I will give it a shot!